# Passing properties of an object vs passing an object

Tags: c#

Suppose I have an object that looks like this:

```
public class SomeObjectModel
{
   long TheLong {get; set;}
   public string TheString {get; set;}
}
```

At some point in my code, I pass some of the properties of this object into a function:

```
public void SomeFunction(long LongParameter, string StringParameter) { ... }
```

What's the difference, if any, between passing in parameters like this versus refactoring the function to take in SomeObjectModel directly like this:

```
public void SomeFunction(SomeObjectModel TheObject)
{
    long LongParameter = TheObject.TheLong;
    string StringParameter = TheObject.TheString;
}
```

Is there's a difference between the two approaches? Is there a recommended approach?

Comment: Side note: your questions are good as they are, no need to add [thank you not notes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside other differences In the first approach if the *parameter* values are changed the value in the calling method will remain the same but in second case they will change.

If you pass object and later add new properties in the *object* your consuming call will still be able to call the method but for *parameters* you will have to changed the calling class as well.

Answer (score 4):

This *really* depends on the actual domain of the problem.

But according to the Law of Demeter (or principle of least knowledge), you should pass as less information as possible.

This promotes loose coupling - the implementation will simply depend on `long` and `string`, instead of depending on `long`, `string` *aaaand* `SomeObjectModel`.

Comment: +1. Good point for the sample in the question (which look like passing some domain model). Note that there is refactoring to warp many of method arguments into single object where this does not apply (but in such case all properties likely will be read only).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to ask yourself if you'd ever use that method when you do not have, or do not want to create, a SomeObjectModel instance.

You might also ask yourself if the method should be a member of SomeObjectModel, and therefore you wouldn't need to explicitly pass it anything.

This could be considered a very open-ended question and I think others have sufficiently answered it, so I'll stop here.  I just wanted to point out that there are a lot of other things to consider when you design that method.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in extensibility. Adding model properties doens't lead to modifying method signature.

Answer (score 2):

In the latter case (passing the whole object), your call stack will only have one reference, thus be smaller, thus in theory faster.  In the earlier case, each parameter needs to be put on a stack, and with lots of parameters, more needs to be put on the stack, and thus in theory slower.

The latter case also allows you to modify the object itself, where as passing by parameters object cannot be modified.  Also, should ever need to change and pass additional value, you'll need to change function signature in the earlier case, where as leave untouch in the latter case.

Comment: The stack performance thing is probably so trivially small as to be irrelevant.

Comment: @TimS. Yes, indeed.  That's why in both places I said "in theory".  Unless it's a function that gets called million times a second, it's not something that I would keep for design consideration.